# How to apply a whitish overlay on the banner image

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a React project. But this question has nothing to do with React. I came across many solutions but none of them is working for me. Here is my code.

**App.js**

```
...
import bannerimage from "./assets/images/bg-banner.jpeg";
function App() {
  const overlayOnBanner = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    background: "rgba(229,229,229,0.3)",
    backgroundSize: 'cover'
  };

  const banner = {
    width: '100%',
    height: '800px',
    backgroundImage: `url(${bannerimage})`,
    backgroundSize: 'cover'
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div style={overlayOnBanner}>
        <div style={banner}>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>       
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please point out my mistake.

Comment: This isn't really a React question, you can create a runnable snippet from the html and css. In general you can try making the parent `position: relative` and then put the overlay inside of the parent and make it `position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index: 2;`.

Comment: @RobertCorponoi, changed the question little bit

Comment: didnt help. Banner is repeating

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you put the banner (the div with the `backgroundImage`) on the outside and wrap it around the banner overlay, it should be pretty easy to format it how you want. Since the banner doesn't have any content other than the inner `div` and since we're using 100% of the width and height in that inner `div`, the "overlay" will cover the entire image.

Is this what you were looking for?

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
  
    let banner = {
      width: '100%',
      height: '150px',
      backgroundImage: `url(https://source.unsplash.com/daily)`,
      backgroundSize: 'cover',
    };
    let overlayOnBanner = {
      width: '100%',
      height: '100%',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.6)',
      fontSize: 1.5 + 'rem',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      display: 'flex',
      justifyContent: 'center',
      alignItems: 'center',
    }

    return ( <
      div className = 'App'>
        <div style = {banner}>
          <div style = {overlayOnBanner}>
            This is the overlay, inside of the banner. 
           </div> 
        </div> 
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm. Also i realized my parent-child tags were reverse.

Answer (score 1):

this is how i would do it  N.B i didn't pay much attention in styling and all

```css
.overlay {
    position: absolute; 
    top:0;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(229,229,229,0.3); /* Black see-through */
    color: #f1f1f1; 
    width: 100%;
    transition: .5s ease;
    color: white;
    height: 300px;
  }
  .image{
   width: 100%;
   height: 300px;
  }
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/05/05/02/37/sunset-1373171_960_720.jpg" alt="Avatar" class="image">
<div class="overlay"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

### Fixing the code

The problem with your code is that the overlay is placed behind the image. In order to fix the problem, simply switch overlay and the image in the HTML (or JSX in your case).

### A cleaner approach

A element can have both a background image and a background color. A better solution is to remove the overlay element and add this property instead to your banner.

`background: url(${bannerimage}, rgba(229,229,229,0.3);`